# In the free pro-C constructions is enough to verify the universal property for C-groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, profinite-groups

The book Profinite Groups of Ribes-Zalesskii shows the existence of free constructions using a similar ideia in all of them (free pro-C groups, free pro-C products, etc). In these proofs the author using the following fact:

> *"it is enough to check the universal for C-groups because a pro-C group is the inverse limit of C-groups"*.

I'm not sure if I'm able to verify this fact. For example, consider $(F,f)$ free pro-C group over $X$ and suppose that the universal property holds for C-groups. Let $G$ be any pro-C groups and decompose
$$G = \varprojlim G_i$$
where $G_i$ are C-groups. Let $\pi_i: G \to G_i$ epimorphisms (we can assume a surjective inverse system). If $g: X \to G$, then $\pi_i g: X \to G_i$ are in the hypothesis, then there is a continuous map $\varphi_i: F \to G_i$ such that $\varphi_i f = \pi_i g$. Take $\varphi = (\varphi_i)$, then
$$\varphi f = (\varphi_i f) = (\pi_i g) = g?$$
I'm not sure this is true.

Comment: That's more or less the idea, yes. The extra thing you have to check is that the there is a commutative square when you have $i \geq j$ and the maps $\varphi_i$, $\varphi_j$, $\text{id}_F$ and $\pi_{ij} \colon G_i \to G_j$ (following your notation for what would be the transition maps). If this square commutes, then you can pass the limit (here, you are taking a "constant" inverse limit over the poset $I$ in which all groups are $F$ and the maps are the identity and the inverse limit $G$) and you'll have the $\varphi$ above which will satisfy the property you want.